# Using Chroot with a Java application

Tags: java, chroot

I'm working on designing a group of Java programs that I hope to turn into a Java-based OS someday. Until I get a kernel working, I want to just run them on top of Ubuntu. Because of this, I need all filesystem calls directed to a different directory in my home folder, so accessing `/` from within Java would actually access `/home/<user>/Thunderbolt/`.

I've looked at the [community documentation for using `chroot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot), but it says to set up a basic installation of Ubuntu in it. Is this really necessary? All I want is to run Java applications inside it so the app thinks it is in its own fake filesystem. I don't want all the extra Ubuntu stuff.

According to the aforesaid docs:

> In many ways, a chroot is like installing another operating system inside your existing operating system.

But I don't want this. All I want is to hide most of the real filesystem from the app so it sees only one directory.

I've also seen the manpage for the [`chroot` function](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/chroot.2.html). Will this do what I want?

**Is there any simple way to run a Java application in its own fake filesystem using `chroot` (without all the extra Ubuntu stuff), and if so, how?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was create a directory called `Thunderbolt` in my home folder. Then for the executables I wanted, I ran `ldd` and copied the needed libraries and the actual executable into my `Thunderbolt` directory, like

```
$ ldd /bin/bash
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7781000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb7743000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb773e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7593000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7782000)
```

For Java itself, along with copying the needed libraries, I used `mount --bind` to bind the Java home directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`):

```
$ mount --bind -o ro /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/ sys/java/
```

To run the `chroot`, I created a script called `thunderbolt` that called `.profile` (which set up the environment) than ran my Java app (`/sys/Thunderbolt.sys` is a Jar file, I just changed the extension):

```
source /.profile
/sys/java/bin/java -jar /sys/Thunderbolt.sys Files
```

To run the `chroot`, I used the following command

```
sudo chroot /home/mspencer/Thunderbolt /bin/bash /thunderbolt
```

**NOTE:** This doesn't work perfectly yet, I'm getting this warning whenever I run Java: `OpenJDK Server VM warning: Can't detect initial thread stack location - find_vma failed`